# Why would this law apply?

Tags: european-union, competition, antitrust-law, tfeu

An Extract from Article 102 of the Treaty on the Functioning of the European Union (TFEU) prohibits:

> (a) directly or indirectly imposing unfair purchase or selling prices or other unfair trading conditions;

From my research it has been implemented mainly in pharmaceutical(Pfizer/Flynn) and food industry(United brands).
But it has also been implemented in the non-essential industries - technology(Rambus & IMAX).

Doesn't this goes against the core of the free market and why does the CJEU believe it is fair to limit how much can be made for **non-essential** goods or services, especially when the customer has a choice *not* to buy those goods?

Furthermore, wouldn't this automatically bring luxury brands such as Louis Vuitton under fire because they naturally have very large markups, which are not at all relative to the risk?

Comment: Anti-drugs laws are against free market. Not being allowed to sell stolen goods is against free market. Abolishing slavery was against the free market.

Comment: And free market is including the right of others to compete, which is made impossible by predatory pricing. If company A accepts losses to drive company B out of business, the result is a restricted market, not a free market.

Comment: @gnasher729 While I agree with your view on predatory pricing, my question is in response to when the CJEU said companies made "excessive" profits. https://www.gov.uk/cma-cases/investigation-into-the-supply-of-pharmaceutical-products I should've provided links in advance - my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

### Unfair trading usually means selling below cost or engaging in cartel behaviour

LV is not captured because they sell well above the cost of production, distribution, and retail.

The type of behaviour that is captured is known as predatory pricing where a large competitor sells below cost in a market to drive smaller competitors out of business either by cross-subsidies from other markets or by simply absorbing the losses from greater capital reserves. A large North American coffee company has been accused of doing this when expanding into new markets.

Another type of unfair practice is actively conspiring with your competitors to agree a market price, or to not compete in other dimensions - perhaps by agreeing not to advertise in certain markets. This deprives consumers of choice because there is no price differentiation or there is no opportunity to learn about competition.

Other types of (arguable) unfair practices is buying up your competitors or refusing to supply certain markets (i.e. tacit or explicit agreements not to compete).

Comment: I understand that predatory pricing and price-fixing is most certainly uncompetitive but for the aforementioned cases, all of them were in reference to making "excessive" profit by dominant undertaking[s].